# PHP generic class to manage multiple tables

Tags: php, wrapper

Is it feasible to create a generic class to handle CRUD operations on multiple tables in a MVC pattern or should I create the models, views and controllers to handle this simple task for all the tables in the system (around 200 tables)? Yet, there would be a "problem". JavaScript would have to be built dynamically also.

So, basically. Does it worth the time that would have to be spent creating this "code generator" or should I stick coding everything in the software?

Comment: Don't get caught up in doing something a particular way because it's popular. Why go to all the effort of creating and maintaining hundreds of different models/views/controllers if you can create a handful of files that will get the job done?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are starting down a path that will eventually lead you to write your own [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

Save yourself some time (and pain!) and investigate some of the ORMs that are currently available. You may find one that fits your needs. When working in PHP, I like to use [Doctrine2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html).

Comment: Chris, even though using an ORM I would have to create the methods inside each controller and reference the model class to make CRUD operations in the database. Let me make things clear. There is a senior developer in my company which has created a generic table management "form" using Delphi. But there things are a little bit simpler. Basically there is a DBGrib associated with a DBNavigator and all the maintenance for support table can be done fast and easy.    They want the same to be done in PHP even if it means to handle all requests in a single route. This doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: @Martignoni, I'm having trouble following this comment. Please update your question with relevant code snippets so we can understand the problem.

Comment: Chris, let me try to explain the question again. I'd like to know if the time that would have to be spent creating a small set of classes that would handle the CRUD operations (including HTML form generation) for any table in the database could have any benefit. Actually I think the question is a bit fuzzy. I haven't seem anything like this on any PHP application up to now.

Comment: @Martignoni, are you looking for something like [what Django provides with its admin interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial02/#explore-the-free-admin-functionality)?